# Rearrangement inequality with infinite variables

Tags: infinity, rearrangement-inequality

Is the rearrangement inequality generalizable for infinite number of variables?

In other words if I have an infinite sum

$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... $

And we can change the order of the coefficients. If we know that $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots$ is it always optimal to choose $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \dots$ if we want to maximize the sum?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Why would you be interested in this question? Do you want to solve a particular problem with this method, for example?

Comment: The answer is yes. You can show that the suspected optimal configuration is as least as good as any other configuration by: taking a finite part of the other configuration and arguing, using a finite rearrangement inequality, that the optimal configuration is bigger than the finite part of the other configuration, and then taking a limit as the length of the finite part increases.

Comment: If you didn't choose a decreasing sequence for both, I wonder how else they should converge. Indeed, we should have at least one of the sequences, either of $x_i$ or $a_i$ converging to $0$ as $i\to\infty.$

Comment: @Allawonder: But convergence to $0$ doesn't imply monotonicity.